# New line with jquery text()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

i have to display on my web page this code in this matter (7 rows in all). This `<code>` is only to display and best use is to copy and to paste for own use.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
wg_width = '250px';
wg_height = '250px';
wg_lines = '3';
wg_bgcolor = '#003366';
</script>
<script src="wg.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

my jquery function to display code is:

```
function upcode(rec,w,h,color) {
var wHTML = ""; 
wHTML += ('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript">\n');
wHTML += ("wg_lines = '" + rec + "';\n");
wHTML += ("wg_width = '" + w + "';\n");
wHTML += ("wg_height = '" + h + "';\n");
wHTML += ("wg_bgcolor = '" + color + "';\n");
wHTML += ('</scr' + 'ipt>\n');
wHTML += ('<scr' + 'ipt src="wg.js" type="text/javascript"></scr' + 'ipt>');
$("#box_code").text(wHTML);
}
```

Unfortunately my output is on 1 row only and it is no good

```
<script type="text/javascript">wgppn_lines = '5'; wgppn_width ='250px'; wgppn_height = '250px';wgppn_bgcolor = '#FF0000';</script> <script src="wgppn.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

i tried also with `html()` method and `<br>` but this method strips out `<script>` tag displayng only

```
wg_width = '250px';
wg_height = '250px';
wg_lines = '3';
wg_bgcolor = '#003366';
```

Comment: Add the following CSS rule: `#box_code{white-space:pre;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could enclose the text in `<pre>` tags:

```
wHTML = $('<div></div>').text(wHTML).html(); // let jQuery escape it for us
$('#box_code').html('<pre>'+wHTML+'</pre>');
```

You could make box code behave like a pre with the following CSS:

```
#box_code { white-space: pre; }
```

You could also change your syntax to use `&lt;script&gt` instead of `<script>` and so on, then put in `<br />` tags manually, but this seems a bit tedious.

Comment: nice one...but i dont need to dislapy <pre></pre>

Comment: @Massimo ah right, I added a little trick that will fix that for you; jQuery is happy to escape the code for you and then you can drop it in with <pre> tags; also, the second option is the most elegant in my opinion